# Is it definitely illegal to refer to a reserved name?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

On the *std-proposals* list, the following code was given:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void foo(const std::vector<int> &v) {
#ifndef _ALGORITHM
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i){std::cout << i; }
#endif
}
```

Let's ignore, for the purposes of *this* question, why that code was given and why it was written that way (as there was a good reason but it's irrelevant here). It supposes that `_ALGORITHM` is a header guard inside the standard header `<algorithm>` as shipped with some known standard library implementation. There is no inherent intention of portability here.

Now, `_ALGORITHM` would of course be a reserved name, per:

> `[C++11: 2.11/3]:` In addition, some identifiers are reserved for use by C++ implementations and standard libraries (17.6.4.3.2) and shall not be used otherwise; no diagnostic is required.
>
> `[C++11: 17.6.4.3.2/1]:` Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore `_ _` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

I was always under the impression that the intent of this passage was to prevent programmers from *defining*/*mutating*/*undefining* names that fall under the above criteria, so that the standard library implementors may use such names without any fear of conflicts with client code.

But, on the *std-proposals* list, it was claimed that this code is itself ill-formed for merely referring to such a reserved name. I can now see how the use of the phrase "shall not be used otherwise" from `[C++11: 2.11/3]:` may indeed suggest that.

One practical rationale given was that the macro `_ALGORITHM` could expand to some code that wipes your hard drive, for example. However, taking into account the likely intention of the rule, I'd say that such an eventuality has more to do with the obvious implementation-defined* nature of the `_ALGORITHM` name, and less to do with it being outright illegal to refer to it.

** "implementation-defined" in its English language sense, not the C++ standard sense of the phrase*

I'd say that, as long as we're happy that we are going to have implementation-defined results and that we should investigate what that macro means on our implementation (if it exists at all!), it should not be inherently illegal to refer to such a macro provided we do not attempt to modify it.

For example, code such as the following is used *all over the place* to distinguish between code compiled as C and code compiled as C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and I've never heard a complaint about that.

So, what do you think? Does "shall not be used otherwise" include simply writing such a name? Or is it probably not intended to be so strict (which may point to an opportunity to adjust the standard wording)?

Comment: The code does not have implementation-defined results. The term "implementation-defined" means that the implementation must document it. There is no such requirement in this case. The code's behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: What do you mean by "illegal"? I don't believe the standard uses that term.

Comment: `__cplusplus` is defined by the standard.  `_ALGORITHM` is reserved by the standard to be used by implementations.  These seem quite different?  I guess using `__cplusplus` in `C` mode is technically "just as bad" as using `_ALGORITHM`, but this question is a [tag:c++] question, not a [tag:c] question.

Comment: Note that this has been elevated to a core language rule: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1882

Comment: @KeithThompson: I use the term in its English language sense. The value and indeed behaviour of `_ALGORITHM` will of course depend on whether the implementation even defined it and, if so, as what.

Comment: @Yakk: Good point, however this is just yet another contradiction with the phrase _"certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation"_. I'm more and more convinced that this is all under-specified.

Comment: In the English sense of "illegal", nobody is going to arrest you for using a reserved identifier.

Comment: @Keith: I feel like you're being _unconstructively_ pedantic, an impressive feat on a language-lawyer question! :) I'm not convinced that there is anything terribly unclear about what I'm asking here, even though I do not posit precisely what form such illegality would take within the scope of the standard.

Comment: The C++ standard uses the term illegal (in a different context) but doesn't elaborate on what it means (see C.1.6)

Comment: _"it was claimed that this code is itself ill-formed for merely referring to such a reserved name"_ That's typical of the nonsense you get in the stupid-proposals group. If the implementation documents such a name as part of its public API then there's nothing ill-formed about it (e.g. `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for libstdc++). In this case it's not part of the documented API meant for users to use, so it has one of undefined/unspecified behaviour, but that's not the same as ill-formed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: _"That's typical of the nonsense you get in the stupid-proposals group"_ Really? [It was Ville who made the claim](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/mZN8_tvVOeg/4RLBksht6rYJ). ;) Anyway, I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit, I'll have a word with him! ;)

Comment: @Alex: True, but Annex C is not normative.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: Yes, I"m being pedantic, but not *deliberately* unconstructive. My point is that "illegal" is a vague term. Obviously you don't mean it in the sense of violating criminal law, but consider: each of `i = i++;`, `int n = &foo;`, and `#error "This must be rejected"` might reasonably be called "illegal", but they're three different kinds of illegality, and the standard uses distinct terms for each of them. (I'm more familiar with the C standard than with the C++ standard; I might post an answer expanding on my thoughts later.)

Comment: @Keith: I could have written "ill-formed" in the title, instead, to match the original _std-proposals_ claim, but I didn't wish to overly constrain things. I'm happy with the ambiguity you mention: an acceptable answer (and there are several below) further defines _how_ the code is "illegal", if indeed it is. After all, the question is the question, not an answer. :)

Comment: Sadly, I see that Keith already beat me to suggesting that you would indeed be arrested for such usage. :) I've seen some code that probably should have resulted in the programmer being arrested over the years.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whether it's legal or not is implementation-specific (and identifier-specific).

When the Standard gives the implementation the sole right to use these names, that includes the right to make the names available in user code.  If an implementation does so, great.

But if an implementation doesn't expressly give you the right, it is clear from "shall not be used otherwise" that the Standard does not, and you have undefined behavior.

Comment: It's looking that way innit

Answer (score 17):

The important part is **"reserved to the implementation"**. It means that the compiler vendor may use those names and even document them. Your code may then use those names as documented. This is often used for extensions like `__builtin_expect`, where the compiler vendor avoids any clash with your identifiers (that are *declared* by your code) by using those reserved names. Even the standard uses them for things like `__attribute__` to make sure it doesn't break existing (legal) code when adding new features.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought, but "your code may then use those names as documented" conflicts with "shall not be used otherwise". Hence the question.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Well, **otherwise**. I understand that the standard does not make it legal or illegal itself, it reserves this right to the implementation. Your compiler vendor then makes the decision, the default is "nope, don't use it". But *otherwise*, if they document those identifiers, it does become legal.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1882

> Each identifier that contains a double understore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.

*any use*.  (similar text occurs both before and after that defect fix is applied)

`__cplusplus` is defined by the standard. `_ALGORITHM` is reserved by the standard to be used by implementations. These seem quite different?  (The two sections of the standard do conflict, in that one states that `__cplusplus` is reserved for any use, and another uses it specifically, but I think that the winner of that conflict is clear).

The `_ALGORITHM` identifier could, under the standard, be used as part of a pre-processing step to say "replace this source code with hard drive deleting code".  Its existence (prior to pre-processing, or after) could be sufficient to completely change your program behavior.

Now this is unlikely, but I do not think it results in an non-conforming implementation.  It is a matter of quality of implementation only.

An implementation is free to document and define what `_ALGORITHM` means.  For example, it could document that it is a header guard for `<algorithm>`, and indicates if that header file has been included.  Treating your current `<algorithm>` implementation as documentation is probably going to far.

I'd guess using `__cplusplus` in C mode is technically "just as bad" as using `_ALGORITHM`, but this question is a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) question, not a [c](/questions/tagged/c) question.  I haven't delved into the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard to look for quotes about it.

Comment: _"`__cplusplus` is defined by the standard. `_ALGORITHM` is reserved by the standard to be used by implementations. These seem quite different?"_ No, I don't think that they are. The wording quoted in this question does not make any exception for names that may be specifically defined elsewhere. In fact, it quite strongly says that there _aren't_ any exceptions ("always", "shall not" and so on).

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit *nod* -- I agree, that conflict looks like a standard defect, as one says that `__cplusplus` could be `42` (as that is one "use" of `__cplusplus`), and the other mandates it has a specific value.  (or more insane uses, like "insert nasal demons for later deployment").  That is a direct contradiction in the standard.  I just think that the intended "victor" of that contradiction is far more clear than "such identifiers may not be magic" requirement implied by your question (and that gcc violates a lot with `__` magic identifiers).

Comment: I would agree with that.

Comment: There's no conflict, everything in the standard has an implicit "unless otherwise specified" and the meaning of `__cplusplus` is otherwise specified. The specific wins over the general. Besides, the "use" of `__cplusplus` that you suggest conflicts with [reserved.names] is by necessity part of the implementation, so it's reserved for any use, and the implementation makes one particular use of it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I propose that the word "always" strongly overrules an implicit "unless otherwise specified".

Comment: OK, but the specific meaning of `__cplusplus` is still defined by the implementation, and reserved for the implementation to define to a specific value, so I still don't see a conflict. [global.names] doesn't say the implementation must do something whacky with every reserved name, it just says they are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @jona it says the implementation can put the identifier to *any use*.  It also says it must have a specific value.  These contradict each other.  Using 'specific beats general' common sense resolves it, but that isn't encoded in the standard.  A clause "unless othere=wise specified by the standard" would also handle it.  I think the defect here is very minor (as everyone knows whwt it means for `__cplusplus`), but it exists.  A practical problem would be later standard iterations stealing *more* identifiers like that.

Comment: You are practising excessive language lawyering. The standard does not say implementations **must** put `__cplusplus` to "any use", that would be moronic. Clearly there is one use for it, which all implementations agree on. But it's still reserved for the implementation to define, not users. And there is no practical problem with later standards stealing more identifiers, because the people working on the standard include lots of implementors, who will be able to avoid the problem. So it's a purely theoretical wankery problem, not a practical one at all.

Comment: Put another way, are you really suggesting that [global.names] should say "Each name that begins with a double underscore [...] is reserved to the implementation for any use, except the ones listed in [cpp.predefined] and blah blah which are reserved to the implementation for the specified use." ? Does that clarify anything? Is it a practical improvement? I don't think so. Calling it a defect is pointless wankery.

Comment: Does the standard specify whether a preprocessor is required to ignore `__fnord` in a section of code that is `#ifdef`ed out, or whether `#ifdef __fnord` can do anything other than cause the following text to be either included if the implementation defines `__fnord` as a macro or excluded if it does not?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: If the people writing the C standards throughout the decades had been asked whether most forms of Undefined Behavior should be exempt from not only the laws of time but also the laws of causality, how many do you think would have indicated the affirmative?  While few might have thought it silly to add language saying "...the standard imposes no requirements *beyond the honoring of data dependencies and causality*", the existence of such text could have had some significant effects on C's development.

Comment: IIRC the C folks have acknowledged `__cplusplus`; it has a special status unlike `_ALGORITHM`. In particular, `#if defined(_cplusplus)` is well-defined and obviously false.

Comment: @supercat: Well, the C++ Standard, all the way back to ISO/IEC 14882:1998, does affirm exemption from the laws of causality.  "However, if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this International Standard places no requirement on the implementation executing that program with that input (not even with regard to operations preceding the ﬁrst undefined operation)."

Comment: @BenVoigt: That doesn't imply any intention to negate the laws of causality.  Even such basic optimizations like strength reduction could cause some operations to happen out of sequence; if a pointer dereference gets hoisted out of a loop for purposes of strength reduction, it could cause a crash that precedes an operation that precedes the attempted dereference within the loop.  "Modern" compilers' negation of the laws of causality goes well beyond such things.

Comment: @supercat: So you're saying that it does negate the laws of causality, but that it's not unique in that respect, correct?

Comment: @BenVoigt: According to the Rationale, the authors of the Standard viewed an implementation's choice how to process many forms of Undefined Behavior as a "quality of implementation" issue; the Standard thus allows many things the authors would not intend that any quality implementations would actually do.  The Standard allows *causally-unrelated* operations to be performed in arbitrary sequence in cases where it does not *define* any means of observing the actual sequence; the fact that UB might make it possible to determine which operation occurs first does not mean the sequence is...

Comment: ...considered "observable".  I think the clause about assuming infinite loops terminate was intended to serve a similar purpose.  The fact that the Standard would not forbid an implementation from deciding that it can assume condition X is true because UB would result if it weren't does not imply judgment that such behavior is appropriate in quality implementations intended for any particular purpose, since the Standard makes no attempt to forbid every silly thing that implementations might do to make themselves unsuitable for various purposes (or even for any purpose whatsoever).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Another thing to consider about reserved names is that the authors of the Standard want to allow implementations broad discretion to add new identifiers that behave in any fashion they think is useful.  If the authors of an implementation intended for use by exhibiters at a demon zoo happened to think it would be useful to have a compiler release nasal demons when given a file that starts with `__nasalDemons`, the authors of the Standard would want to allow that.  To do so, the Standard must treat as UB nearly all uses of identifiers that a compiler could treat in such fashion.

Answer (score 4):

The names in [cpp.predefined] are different. Those have a specified meaning, so an implementation can't reserve them for any use, and using them in a program has a well-defined portable meaning. Using an implementation-specific identifier like the example of _ALGORITHM is ill-formed because it violates a shall-rule.

Yes, I'm fully aware of multiple examples where the library specification uses "shall" to mean "this is a requirement on user code, and violations are UB, not ill-formed".

Regarding whether it's UB or implementation-defined, running an ill-formed program results in UB. The standard wording clearly says the program is ill-formed, UB occurs if the implementation still chooses to accept the program and run it.

So, if a program uses the identifier _ALGORITHM, that program is ill-formed, and running such a program is UB, but that does not mean it doesn't work fine on an implementation that uses _ALGORITHM as an include guard, nor does it mean that it doesn't work fine on an implementation that doesn't.

If users are concerned about such ill-formedness and potential UB, and said users want to write portable C++, they shouldn't use reserved identifiers in portable C++ programs. If users accept that regardless of the standard prohibiting such a use, no practical implementation will wipe your hard drive, they can freely use such reserved identifiers, but by the letter of the standard, such uses are still ill-formed.

Comment: What would be the best way of writing code which is e.g. supposed to run optimally on one particular compiler but run correctly on any, if *optimal* behavior on the intended compiler would require use of reserved tokens?  Use conditional compilation to map non-reserved tokens to (possibly empty) token sequences that will work on whatever compiler is being used?

Comment: Do you seriously believe that writing  
    `#ifdef __IMPL_SPECIFIC_NAME`  
has a practically reasonable chance of wiping your hard drive? :)

Comment: Until recently, I would not have believed that any compiler given `int f(int x) { if (x >= 0) launch_missiles(); return x<<1; }` would generate code that would call `launch_missiles()` when `x` is negative, but some compiler writers have fought for the right to have it do so [from what I read, the Committee was considering changing a left-shift of a negative value be Implementation-Defined, but that was vetoed on the basis that it would "impair optimizations"].

Comment: It seems to me that it might be reasonable to clarify the wording in the standard to say that an `#ifdef __WHAT_EVER_IDENTIFIER` is not ill-formed even if the identifier is a reserved name. I don't think that has any practical impact, but I'm not opposed to such clarification.

Regarding that "optimize-on-UB" case, there are factions that are trying to fight back on the implementation vendors' insistence to optimize any UB any way they please.

Comment: What do you know of such efforts toward sensible optimization? Personally, I think some of the inference-based optimization logic could be very useful if it were interfaced to sensible structures in the source code, but UB is the wrong tool for the job.  The goal of a compiler shouldn't be to produce an executable that satisfies the C standard, but rather to help programmers end up with an executable that satisfies the program's requirements.  There are a lot of places where the standard specifies semantics that are more rigid than most programmers require; letting programmers request...

Comment: You didn't address clear contradictions in the standard over this, which suggest the interpretation that it's outright ill-formed is not as easy to reach as it may at first seem.

Comment: ...looser semantics could then enable further optimizations.  There are other places where UB is 100% unhelpful.  For example, I would like to see the rules of integer computation modified so that if the result of a computation is stored to an unsigned type or masked with a positive value, and all bits of an intermediate computation which could affect the outcome would fit in a positive `int`, the result of that computation should be the same as if it was performed with modulo arithmetic.  Semantically, having code which wants to multiply a `unsigned short` variable by another first...

Comment: ...ensure that the second variable gets promotes to `unsigned int` is nonsensical.  A fundamental pretense of C is that unsigned values work according to the rules of modular arithmetic; I've seen no indication that shorter unsigned values were intended not to be safely usable in such fashion.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of a simpler rule which the C standard could add, since I can't think of any programs it would break on common platforms, or any realistic programs it would break on any platform: if the result of an integral binary `+ - * << % & |` or unary `+ - ~` operator is coerced or cast to an unsigned type smaller than that result, the result shall be as if the operation was performed on that type and its operands coerced or cast likewise.  Historically, I suspect such a rule would have been included in the C standard *but for the fact that all implementations...*

Comment: *...probably behaved that way anyhow even without the rule*.  It's possible that the product of two unsigned shorts, even coerced to unsigned short, could have yielded a different behavior on a machine using non-two's-complement math, but I doubt any implementation ever promised such behavior, and I can't think of any way it could ever be useful [indeed, even on a non-two's-complement hardware, computing the modular-arithmetic result may be faster than computing anything else]

Comment: @supercat: `%` shouldn't be on that list, as `uint8_t(277 % 514)` is not the same as `uint8_t(277) % uint8_t(514)`.  http://rextester.com/LDOW11060

Comment: @BenVoigt: You're correct; a weaker version of the rule could be applied to that operator, but the rule as stated is too broad and thus not applicable.  Otherwise, what would you think of the proposed rule.  When about would you guess that the first two's-complement general-purpose (non-sanitizing) implementation that would behave in contrary fashion was produced?  Present versions of gcc do sometimes behave in contrary fashion, but I don't think twentieth-century versions did.  Any idea which two's-complement implementation "broke the dam"?

Comment: @supercat: I don't like the rule, if it gives equivalent results it's already legal for an optimizer to substitute it under the "as-if" rule, and if it doesn't give equivalent results in all cases then it could lead to bugs.  I guess you're actually trying to make overflow well-defined when the output is stored as unsigned, but then why do you require the output to be smaller?  I think for intuitive behavior, you'd want to coerce operands to the larger of the output type and the unsigned version of the operand expression's type.  But I still don't like it.

Comment: @supercat: Instead of changing behavior based on casts/conversion done later in the syntax tree, why not use the mismatch to generate warnings?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Many compilers for 8-bit architectures (with 16-bit "int") have, since the 1980s, applied the indicated rule in their code generation so that a compiler given `uchar1=uchar2+uchar3;` won't bother generating code that computes the MSB of the result.  Further, the only thing compilers targeting two's-complement silent-wraparound hardware would need to do to honor the proposed rule is refrain from inferring that operands won't have values that would cause overflow on intermediate results, since evaluation on two's-complement hardware will...

Comment: ...naturally abide the rules of modular arithmetic since the modulus used by smaller types divides into the modulus of larger types.  If x+y is congruent to z, mod 65536, it will also be congruent to z, mod 256, and likewise for the other operators listed [not counting `%` of course].

Comment: @supercat: Oh I agree that compilers are already taking advantage of dataflow analysis to avoid calculating discarded bits.  The "as-if" rule already permits that.  "inferring that operands won't overflow" is exactly the basis of a whole lot of useful optimizations, and giving overflow well-defined behavior doesn't make the program any less buggy than it already was.  You're talking about cases where the developer didn't give any thought at all to overflow, how can you come in after the fact and determine that wraparound (not saturation) is the appropriate behavior in 100% of cases?

Comment: @BenVoigt: If the result of an integer computation is stored into e.g. a uint16_t, the fact that the result is being stored into a uint16_t implies that if the value is outside the range 0-65535, the code should store the mod-65536 residual.  Given `uint16_t x;`, does it make more sense to say that `x*=y;` should store the mod-65536 residual of the product if it is in the range 0..2147483647, and jump the rails if it's larger, or does it make more sense to say that the purpose is to store the mod-65536 residual regardless of the size of the product?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm also curious, btw, how many *useful* optimizations would be precluded if compilers' overflow behavior were limited to behaving as though overflowed values may behave, non-deterministically, as any number (not necessarily representable) which is congruent to the arithmetically-correct value, modulo the integer range.  That would allow a compiler to replace `x+1>y` with `x>=y`, since in case of overflow the value `x+1` could behave (among other possibilities) as a value one larger than INT_MAX.

Comment: @supercat: Ah well, I think it would be better for unsigned types (which have well-defined overflow semantics) never to be promoted to any type having undefined overflow.  Implicit conversion, sure, but never promotion.  Shucks I should have brought that up in Issaquah last week while I was talking to the committee.

Comment: @supercat: What does "congruent to the arithmetically-correct value" buy you vs just changing integer overflow from undefined behavior to having an unspecified result but no side effects?  But even that is potentially very painful for systems which have hardware traps on overflow (yeah yeah just use the unsigned hardware operation instead... but those may not behave as needed). I'd also hate to break platforms that take advantage of the current flexibility to provide their users with a strong guarantee that overflowing signed operations saturate (I think some GPGPU toolchains work like this).

Comment: @BenVoigt: In the example of `uint16_t x=y*z;` where the computation will be used in something like a hash function that requires modular arithmetic, having `y*z` yield a result in case of overflow which is congruent to the correct result mod 65536 would make the computation work.  Yielding a result not congruent mod 65536 would make the computation fail.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Further, requiring that a computation yield an unspecified result would cause difficulty in cases where a compiler might be able to use one chain of inference to infer that `x*y` is greater than `z`, and another to prove that it can't be greater than `z`.  No single unspecified value could support both inferences.  Allowing a result to non-deterministically behave as a number which is greater than `z` or one that's less than `z` would change the first inference to "the compiler may at its leisure treat the number as greater than z", and the second to...

Comment: ..."the compiler may at its leisure treat the number as less than z".  The two revised inferences would not contradict each other, and the program could stay on the rails while abiding both.

Comment: I recognize that it is useful for specialized implementations to use alternative integer semantics, but would view the situation as analogous to that of floating-point and Annex F: the fact that some implementations cannot support certain guarantees should not preclude the usefulness of such guarantees to code which does not need to run on those implementations.  Quality implementations should endeavor to support such guarantees when practical, even if conforming implementations could opt instead to simply report (via macro) that the guarantees are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, the purpose for making the use of such tokens "undefined behavior" is that compilers are free to attach any meaning they want to any such token that are not defined within the C standard.  For example, on some embedded processors, using __xdata as a storage class for a variable will ask that it be stored in an area of RAM which is slower to access than the normal variable-storage area, but is much larger.  On typical processors of that family, storage for "normal" variables would be limited to about 100 bytes, but storage for xdata variables may be much larger--up to 64K.  The standard says basically nothing about what compilers are allowed to do with such directives, although typically (I'm not sure if the standard mandates this behavior, though I'm unaware of compilers violating it) such tokens are generally ignored within code that is disabled using a `#if` or similar directives.

Some libraries' header files will start their own internal identifiers with something that starts with two underscores but includes a pattern that's unlikely to be used by a compiler for any purpose (e.g. version 23 of the Foozle library might precede its identifiers with use `__FZ23`).  It would be perfectly legitimate for a future compilers to use identifiers starting with __FZ23 for other purposes, and if that were to happen the Foozle library would need to be changed to use something else.  If, however, it is likely that a major compiler upgrade would likely necessitate rewrites of the Foozle library for other reasons anyway, that risk may be acceptable compared to the risk of identifiers conflicting with outside code.

Note also that some project header files which are targeted toward a processor that requires `__` directives may conditionally define macros with those names when compiled for other processors, for example:

```
#ifndef USE_XDATA
#define __XDATA
#endif
```

though a somewhat better pattern would generally be:

```
#ifdef USE_XDATA
#define XDATA __XDATA
#else
#define XDATA
#endif
```

When writing new code, the latter pattern is often better, but the former pattern may sometimes be useful when adapting existing code written on a platform that requires __XDATA so that it may be used both on platforms that use/require that directive and on platforms that do not.

Comment: Second-last line of code shouldn't have any underscores, correct?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Corrected.  BTW, what do you think of the answer?  Do you know whether the standard would imply that a compiler cannot do anything weird with a `__*` token that's in part of the code ignored by `#ifdef`, nor that is used in `#ifdef __*` or `#if defined(__*)` [beyond, in the latter cases, arbitrarily considering it to be defined or not at its leisure]?

Comment: @supercat: If I were a compiler writer, I would understand "reserved to the implementation" to imply I'm allowed to let `#if defined(__flarg)` produce a syntax error because my lexer had identified `__flarg` as a keyword instead of an identifier.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Is there anything that would particularly authorize the preprocessor to do anything with the argument to `defined(...)` other than determine if a macro exists with the indicated name?  I would guess there's a gap in the standard as a consequence of it being written in a style that predates modern protocol documentation language (MUST, SHOULD, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it is legal is a matter of local law. Whether it means anything, and if so, what, is a matter for the language definition. When you use a name that's reserved to the implementation the behavior of your program is undefined. That means that the language definition does not tell you what the program does. Nothing more, nothing less. If the compiler you're using documents what a particular reserved identifier does, then you can use that identifier with that compiler. If you hunt through headers and guess what various un-documented identifiers mean you might be able to use them, but don't be surprised if your code breaks when a subsequent update changes something.

Don't get hung up on `__cplusplus`. It's core language, and the stuff about double underscores, etc. is library. If that's not convincing, just consider it a glitch. You can use `__cplusplus` in C++ programs; its meaning is well defined.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is at worst riddled with contradictions and at best does not do anything to explain the standard's contradictions with any reasoning or proof. It's just a slew of assertions, most of which I already made in the question.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit - since you do not mention what contradictions you think you see in my answer, I can't respond to that sweeping claim. My answer sets out how you go about analyzing issues like this; it's an area where people often get confused.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit - um, what? You've gone from "riddled with contradictions" to "does not ... explain" to something about other answers? Thanks for wasting my time.

Comment: First of all, there is no need to be abusive and hostile. Second of all, there is nothing incoherent or "wasteful" about what I've said. It makes complete sense. You questioned my so-called "sweeping claim", and I pointed you to where you can find the information you sought. Do not blame me for your lack of comprehension abilities! Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing contradictory in what I wrote. If you don't understand it, ask for clarification.

Comment: Since you have again declined to support your assertion that my answer "is ... riddled with contradictions", it's clear that you have abandoned it.

Comment: But, for the purposes of enhancing your knowledge, and since you obviously can't be bothered to read the other comments on this page (as I invited you to do 20 hours ago, shortly before you got arrogant and hostile): _"When you use a name that's reserved to the implementation the behavior of your program is undefined."_ ~ _"You can use `__cplusplus` in C++ programs; its meaning is well defined."_

Comment: What can I say? Obviously, twenty years on the C++ standards committee, co-chair of the Library Working Group, six years as project editor for C++11, several years of columns, and a book doesn't give me anywhere near the credentials that you obviously have. You're quite good at selective reading and misquoting, an expertise that I have not had the ambition to acquire. Clearly, the import of the last **paragraph** (not just the sentence you lifted out of context) is that the identifier `__cplusplus` is not reserved to the implementation.